# How to make 1 to 1 parent-child dataverse tables in sync on creation of a record

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, dataverse

I've been trying to create 1 to 1 relation in Dataverse, and according to this [post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Dataverse/One-to-one-1-1-relationship-between-tables/td-p/771053) it's not added and not supported yet.

On the other hand, it was suggested to create 1:M and M:1 in both tables to make them related to each other. (which I've made).

I've tried to use power automate to make this step of syncing between two created records between both tables happen, but I keep getting errors while creation of child record.

> What I'm attempting to do:

- On creation of a record in Table-A (Parent) a record on Table-B should be created and a related column in Table-B should be populated with Table-A ID (the newly created record in this table)

> What I tried to attempt on power-automate:
> [image]

A small issue that I've is Table-A & Table-B primary keys (ID) are autogenerated so it tries to do the action of adding the record but always gets erros.

> Errors that I get

Raw input from previous step

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_commondataserviceforapps",
        "operationId": "CreateRecord"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "entityName": "cr855_testchildren",
        "item/cr855_childid": null,
        "item/cr855_ParentID@odata.bind": "1"
    }
}
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "0x80060888",
    "message": "URL was not parsed due to an ODataUnrecognizedPathException. Resource not found for the segment provided in the URL."
  }
}
```

I'm new to power applications (dataverse, power-automate, power-apps....), so please accept my apologize if I'm missing any information in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set/update the lookup field value the content should look like /entitycollectionname(recordid), so something like /cr855_testparents(da1f3c80-70c2-4098-83a4-3e4e87f03d9e)

Comment: I didn't get it, would you explain please?

Comment: Check this article - https://tomriha.com/how-to-update-dataverse-lookup-column-with-power-automate/